# PHP: Searching for specific results in potentially large associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a couple side questions to this but I'll start with what I'm trying to do.

I have an input form where clients will enter some info and their email address, I'm using emails as account identifiers. I want to create an array of emails that it will go through to first check if the email exists in the array, then to check what page to show them...

Something like this:

```
$client_emails = array(
    'email@ex-one.com',
    'email@ex-two.com' => 'page_one',
    'email@ex-three.com' => 'page_two',
    'email@ex-four.com',
    ),
```

So something like this then:

```
if (!empty($form_email)) { // input field variable
    if (in_array($form_email, $client_emails)) {
        // echo content
    }
}
```

So with the above being put out there... I want to (1) check if the email exists, then (2) see if the key has a value and if it does then I need to echo that in its own variable to use. Maybe return it in a function?

I'm thinking that I need to have a variable like `$client_page` and if the function does not return a value to the key (email) then it returns default page.

Pseudo-code:

```
function($client_page)... if (key exists) {
    if (key has value) {
        return value
    } else {
        return default
    }
}
```

I came across an interesting setion on the PHP manual that gave an exaple with `array_flip()`, I'm not sure if that will be useful but it looks like it could be any way:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php#96198

I also came across this question on this site, similar but not the same thing:
[PHP Searching multidimensional associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24340649/php-searching-multidimensional-associative-array)

Any ideas?

---

Side questions:

Considering that the emails that I want to store are sensitive information - is there anything I should be doing to protect this more than just have it in a server-side document? Like using php class's? (I don't know anything about using class's and all of that fun stuff)

Comment: Where would you save this array? Database (recommended)? File?

Comment: @RonDadon it would just be in a php file, but what is the best way to do this? I'm still working out how to store info in the database

Comment: PHP files are "fixed". So if you will add a value to the array lets say from POST by the user, the next time the PHP file will run, the added value will not be there. You must store your data somewhere - in a file or a database.

Comment: @RonDadon oh! no I will be the one adding the values for now any ways, I may make a signup form later on when I connect it to a database - how safe is it to store these emails in a file though?

Comment: As long as you store it outside of your root public directory - that generaly OK, but you'll need to watch out from directory traversal attacks in other places in your code to make sure that the file is not reachable. You can use the function that you showed (in_array) - it will be fast enough even for 5000 recrods

Comment: It isn't clear what is beeing asked here. Provide some numbers, like the number of email addresses.

Comment: @RonDadon so if my path is `pre_root/root_directory/post_root` is it okay to store it in post_root and disallow access to that folder and contents? Right now I'm using php and htaccess to create my visible site structure but the folders are nothing like what people see in the url

Comment: That could be ok, but make sure you can access it from PHP. My idea was to place it in the pre_root in your example.

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan I don't understand what isn't being made clear - you're welcome to ask me questions. At this time I don't know how many email addresses I will be using, definitely under 5000 as stated in the example previous to your comment, at first probably 10 but I want to set it up so I can grow with no problems.

Comment: Did you bother to create an array with 5000 string values and actually use it? It would have taken 1/100th of the time it takes to write this post and involve many people. Just benchmark it, I bet you don't have a problem to begin with.

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan the number of entries isn't the reason I'm asking the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the email addresses as keys, and their respective page as value.

```
$client_emails = array(
    'email@ex-one.com'   => null,
    'email@ex-two.com'   => 'page_one',
    'email@ex-three.com' => 'page_two',
    'email@ex-four.com'  => null
);

if (null !== $form_email) {
    if (isset($client_emails[$form_email])) {
         $client_page = $client_emails[$form_email];
    }
}

 if (null === $client_page) {
     echo 'You can not be here';
 } else {
     // Handle $client_page
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just curious what's the difference between using != and !== ?

Comment: From php.net: $a == $b Equal TRUE if $a is equal to $b after type juggling. $a === $b Identical TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type. In this case you could also use != (it's more like a habit)

Comment: Oh, so === is just more strict?

Comment: Correct! (when you have two objects but with different values inside of it)

Comment: Okay so what am I doing wrong here? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/245db2528352f512ab4b661e41e2a7cd5030cc6d I appreciate your time

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying to understand it haha, perfect!

Comment: I have a question for you, while searching the array for the email being entered using in_array() I can't get this to work: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5863f923a18e555e0e361266d4af950a59aedd4f I've added an error message at the bottom so you can see what's happening - I'm not sure what's happening but I'd appreciate your help if you can!

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to form an array like `key` is email, `value` is a showed page or `false` for other cases, e.g:

```
$client_emails = array(
    'email@ex-one.com' => false,
    'email@ex-two.com' => 'page_one',
    'email@ex-three.com' => 'page_two',
    'email@ex-four.com' => false,
);
```

In your function you can use plain old `isset`:

```
$test_email = 'sometestemail';
if (isset($client_emails[$test_email]) && $client_emails[$test_email])
    return $client_emails[$test_email];
```

Comment: Wouldn't $client_emails[$test_email]) && $client_emails[$test_email] be checking for the same value twice?

Comment: No. `isset` checks that value is set. That means that it's not NULL. And it it's set then we check for non-emptiness.

Comment: Of course you can use @Armand answer and store `NULL` instead of `false`, then you can check only `isset`.

Answer (score 0):

What is described here is a very innefficent architecture which does not scale well. Even with the code pre-parsed and held in the opcode cache there will come a point (at a guess, around 300-500 records) where it would be more efficient to keep the data in a database. There are also big problems with maintaining the data - to support changes to the list, the code must be self-modifying which makes it very difficult to ensure its security. There are also further issues around the Zend opcode+ cache affecting performance.

And if you control the filesystem then its trivial to map the content more directly....

```
$f=md5($form_email . $salt);
$d=substr($f,0,3);
$f=$base . '/' . $d . '/' . $f;
If (is_readable($f)) {
    Include $f;
} else {
    Include $default;
}
```